# How to destructure `tutor` object in my code to make it smaller?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Some of my codes are repeating like tutor.bla bla. What's the best practice for the code block below? How to destructure `tutor` object?

```
const Tutors = ({ tutors }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {tutors.map((tutor) => (
        <TutorListingCard
          key={tutor.id}
          image={tutor.attributes.profile_photo.data.attributes.url}
          name={tutor.attributes.name}
          surname={tutor.attributes.surname}
          university={tutor.attributes.university}
          services={tutor.attributes.services.data.map((service) => {
            return service.attributes.name;
          })}
          students_helped={tutor.attributes.students_helped.data.length}
          rating={Number.isNaN(getRating(tutor)) ? 0 : getRating(tutor)}
          reviews={tutor.attributes.reviews.data.length}
          biography={tutor.attributes.biography}
          subjects={tutor.attributes.subjects.data.map((subject) => {
            return subject.attributes.name;
          })}
          price={tutor.attributes.price}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Destructure tutor object and then instead of `tutor.attributes` use just `attributes`.
2. Not use a function with only return in it where you can just return the value

```js
services={attributes.services.data.map((service) => service.attributes.name)}
```

So final code would be:

```js
const Tutors = ({ tutors }) => (
  <div>
    {tutors.map((tutor) => {
      const { attributes } = tutor;
      return (
        <TutorListingCard
          key={tutor.id}
          image={attributes.profile_photo.data.attributes.url}
          name={attributes.name}
          surname={attributes.surname}
          university={attributes.university}
          services={attributes.services.data.map((service) => service.attributes.name}
          students_helped={attributes.students_helped.data.length}
          rating={Number.isNaN(getRating(tutor)) ? 0 : getRating(tutor)}
          reviews={attributes.reviews.data.length}
          biography={attributes.biography}
          subjects={attributes.subjects.data.map((subject) => subject.attributes.name)}
          price={attributes.price}
        />
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

This is the most basic thing. Aside from that your component TutorListingCard could also have a data property where you would pass all that information as an object. But unless you are passing an array (which you are not), I'd probably not go that way.

Meaning:

```
{
  tutors.map((tutor) => 
  <TutorListingCard
    key={tutor.id}
    data={tutor}
  />
}
```